# How to use collections function in blade template?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I try to control output flow in Blade template, for this I use collection function inside template:

```
@if(count($item->images))
   @if($item->images->count() > 1 && $item->images->count() < 3)
        {{$chunk = $item->images->forPage(0, 1)}} // It displays $chunk like as object (string) in template
   @endif
@endif
```

After this I try to display collection in `$chunk`:

```
@foreach($chunk as $image)
   // Show here
@endforeach
```

Comment: I'm not able to understand what you want to achieve. Could you please elaborate

Comment: I try to use function forPage in template: `{$chunk = $item->images->forPage(0, 1)`

Comment: After I try to iterate result  `$chunk` in the same template below

Comment: what ever you put between `{{ }}` is printed out with the output of the code between them.

Comment: Yes, I know, but how I can to execute this without print? That after to to display $chunk in loop?

Comment: check my answer, is that what you mean ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you do this,

```
@if(count($item->images))
   @if($item->images->count() > 1 && $item->images->count() < 3)
        @foreach($item->images->forPage(0, 1) as $image)
           // Show here
        @endforeach
   @endif
@endif
```

Comment: Yes, it works, but I tried to do this more elegant with one loop in the end of template.

Comment: This would be the similar I think

Comment: Though you can also use `php` tag <?php\\your code ?>, but its not the standard

Answer (score 1):

```
{{ some code php }}
```

Is the same as

```
<?php echo some php code; ?>
```

NOT the same as

```
<?php some php code; ?>
```

---

What you can do is either just relay the info to the loop:

```
@if(count($item->images))
   @if($item->images->count() > 1 && $item->images->count() < 3)
        @foreach($item->images->forPage(0, 1) as $image)
            // do stuff
        @endforeach
   @endif
@endif
```

Or you can use a package such as radic/blade-extensions (http://robin.radic.nl/blade-extensions/) and use `@set()` to set the variable.

Or you could just use regular PHP in the template, but that's not as nice of course.